# Fermat's Little Theorem and Carmichael Numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, carmichael-numbers

Fermat's little theorem states that if $p$ is a prime number and $a$ is a positive integer, then $p|a^p-a$.

However, the converse is false, that is, for integers $a$ and $p$, if $p|a^p-a$, then $a$ is a prime number, is a false statement. For instant, $561|a^{561}-a$ for some integer $a$, but $561$ is actually a composite number, and such numbers are called "Carmichael numbers".

In other words, a Carmichael number is a composite integer, say $k$, such that $k|a^k-a$ for all integers $a$.

> This is what I know, am I right or I misunderstand something?

and

> Do we have a way to find Carmichael numbers?

Comment: Search the web for _find Carmicael numbers_ https://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/jameson/carfind.pdf

Comment: There is a nice criterion for a squarefree odd composite $N>1$ : $N$ is a Carmichael number if and only if $p-1\mid N-1$ holds for every prime $p\mid N$. If $N$ is not squarefree odd and composite, it cannot be a Carmichael number. Moreover, it can be shown that $N$ must have at least three prime factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers of the form $(6k+1)(12k+1)(18k+1)$ are Carmichael numbers if each of the three factors is prime. This gives some examples - already $k=1$ works. Actually, the sequence [A046025](http://oeis.org/A046025) gives more values, e.g.,

$$
k=1, 6, 35, 45, 51, 55, 56, 100, 121, 195, 206, 216, 255, 276, 370, 380,
 426, 506, 510, 511, 710, 741, 800, 825, 871, 930, 975, 1025, 1060, 1115,
 1140, 1161, 1270, 1280, 1281, 1311, 1336, 1361, 1365, 1381, 1420, 1421, 
1441, 1490, 1515, 1696, 1805, 1875, 1885
$$